# Print raw html strings on EJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express.js with EJS templates and i'm trying to do something like this:

```
<%= "<a href='#'>Test</a>" %>
```

but it prints this:

```
&lt;a href='#'&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
```

how can i print "html safe" strings?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You should use html code everywhere, and use the EJS tags only where you need dynamic data. Example:

```
<a href='<%= user.id %>'><%= user.name %</a>
```

To specifically answer your question you can use `<%- "<tags_here>" %>` to output **unescaped** HTML data.

Comment: the problem is that when i do this:
    <%= partial('my_link') %>

it prints that way too

Comment: Ah if you want html to not be escaped you should do this <%- partial('my_link') %>

Comment: No problem, for more info on EJS check the github repo: https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs

Comment: You could still have answered to the question. What if others come look this question expecting to find out how to print unescaped stuff?

Comment: is there something similar to echo from php that lets you print data from within a `<% %>` statement?

Comment: I know this is really old, but... how would you do this if the raw HTML were stored in a variable? For instance I'm using showdown to convert markdown code to HTML. 

`var rawhtml = new showdown.Converter().makeHtml(...)`

`<%- rawhtml %>` outputs nothing.

Is there a way to dump the output of a variable? I tried making a div and using jQuery to set the contents but it always ends up encoded as an HTML string.

Comment: @David you can even do console.log there, that's how I debugged things.

Answer (score 35):

for raw output html in ejs you can use this code

```
<%- "<a href='#'>Test</a>" %>
```

Answer (score 17):

This are the available options according to the docs

1. <% 'Scriptlet' tag, for control-flow, no output
2. <%_ ‘Whitespace Slurping’ Scriptlet tag, strips all whitespace before it
3. <%= Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)
4. <%- Outputs the unescaped value into the template
5. <%# Comment tag, no execution, no output
6. <%% Outputs a literal '<%'
7. %> Plain ending tag
8. -%> Trim-mode ('newline slurp') tag, trims following newline
9. _%> ‘Whitespace Slurping’ ending tag, removes all whitespace after it

Looks like the option you need is the number 4