# Passing html tags as ejs variables' value

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I'm using Koa Framework and EJS templates to render the views. I need to send some html element values to the view. But the ejs library is converting them to html entities. I'm following how they told in https://www.npmjs.org/package/koa-ejs

In my js file:

```
yield this.render('ejs file name', {
  a: 'hi',
  b: '<a href="hi">hi</a>'
});
```

My view file:

```
<%=a %>
<%=b %>
```

What I'm getting after running the code:

```
hi
&lt;a href="hi"&gt;hi&lt;/a&gt;
```

But I need `<a href="hi">hi</a>` as value not `&lt;a href="hi"&gt;hi&lt;/a&gt;`

Does anyone have any suggestion how to to that?

Comment: you want to use the `partial` function in EJS.

Comment: Can you please describe a bit more? Because I've already used partial but that's not the issue. It's about the values are getting converted into html entities on the fly I pass them to ejs. How to prevent it?

Comment: it would be nice to share the solution with us tho: <%-b%>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution by manually inspecting the module's code. By default the ejs module will escape the values. To prevent it we need to send our own escape function to the module which will overwrite the existing.

```
yield this.render('ejs file name', {
  a: 'hi',
  b: '<a href="hi">hi</a>',
  escape: function(html) {
    return String(html);
    // don't replace the htmls
    //.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
    //.replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    //.replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
    //.replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
    //.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
  }
});
```

Comment: you can similarly use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8125053/648350 (see comments section of linked answer)

Comment: That's not a solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: are you not trying to unescape html in ejs variables? that's what `<%- %>` does: See unescaped buffering in EJS docs https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs

Comment: That's not working either. Please, don't waste your time as I already figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: could you include your EJS file contents in your answer please, are you doing something like `<%= escape(b) %>`?

Answer (score 5):

To deal with EJS and Node JS using a text-editor(i use tinyMCE though) just call the tag into this `<%- <YOUR-VARAIABLE-NAME> %>`, that strips all the tags and render your texts perfectly.