# Using ejs to create a xml file, can I use parse a string into XML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, xml, ejs

I'm trying to generate a xml file using ejs.
I have a string containing a part of this XML, while the rest of it is generated directly in the ejs.

Is there a way to directly put my string into the xml, so that the string is considered like a part of the xml?

I tried adding my string "brutally" with <%=string%>, but it does not recognise most of the symbols; for example, `<` becomes `&lt;`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an answer to a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8125053/2494631

Essentially, use `<%- %>` instead of `<%= %>` to output unescaped XML/HTML.

Answer (score 0):

i used

```
replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>').replace(/&amp;/g,'&')
```

but, this might not be what your looking for.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).