# how to covert &lt; back to <?

Tags: node.js, ejs

i have converted a P tag to send it to my database now retrieving it from my database but node or ejs is not rendering the p tag as a p or a html tag.
i was trying out the ckeditor as a formatting tool to make textarea output as html but it converts the tag into < > and it worked fine for me when using php now in nodejs it doesn't coverts them back to < >

<%=  rs.comment %> //output variable containing <P> as p tag

ideally i want to covert the tags into actual html tag not as a text but ejs or node is not rendering them into html they are just converted into a p tag but my browser it not see them as html tags

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print raw html strings on EJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124583/print-raw-html-strings-on-ejs)

Comment: Did you try `<%- rs.comment %>` ?

Comment: @tadman it worked thanks. i am new to ejs world

Comment: No trouble. As a note, in the future try and put text in the body of your question, not as an image. This helps us because we can copy-paste what you have, edit it, and come up with a solution, not have to start from scratch. It's also searchable, which can be important for unusual error messages.

Comment: sure will do and thanks again