# How to convert string into html format using ejs in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs, router

The scenario is the user will enter the text in HTML format (e.g. `<\/b>Testing<\/b>`) then the inserted text will get saved into the database(HTML code as a string (e.g. `<\b>Testing<\/b>`).

I want the string fetched back from the database to be displayed as HTML text (e.g. **Testing**).

I followed the below snippet but didn't get anything as output.

Note: `<%= cData.description %>` worked fine when executed simply but displayed HTML code as plain text.

**test.js (route file):**

```
var testid = 234123;
b.find(testid, function(data) {
  b.otherdet(testid, function(cdata){
    res.render('blogdesc',{
      Data: data,
      cdata: cdata
    });     
  });
});
```

**test.ejs file:**

```
<p class="" id="descid"></p>

<script>
  var $log = $( "#descid" );
  html = $.parseHTML('<%= cData.description %>'); //description is column in database
  $log.append( html );
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print raw html strings on EJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124583/print-raw-html-strings-on-ejs)

Comment: Thanks @Craicerjack, It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found, where did it go wrong. I was using:

```
html = $.parseHTML('<%=blogData.description%>');
```

while the actual syntax should be this:

```
html = $.parseHTML('<%-blogData.description%>');
```

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8125053/20394 shows how to emit HTML as-is in EJS, but please make sure that you [sanitize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization) that content to avoid XSS.