# JavaScript replacing apostrophe with the HTML entity ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am sending a JavaScript object to my client side, ejs view, and I am trying to access the object in a `<script>` tag. However, the browser renders the apostrophes in the js object as HTML entities instead of an actual apostrophe.

Screenshot of chrome console:

[image: js rendering of object]

Would you be able to suggest what I am doing wrong / how to solve this issue / work around it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print raw html strings on EJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124583/print-raw-html-strings-on-ejs)