# CKEditor5 is not escaping HTML when loading content from database

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, ckeditor5

I have the following in my ejs template:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/41.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>

    // Classic Editor
    ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        ckfinder: {
            uploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json'
        }
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
    
</script>
```

The HTML element looks like this:

```
<div class="mb-3">
   <label for="content" class="form-label">Content</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" id="editor" rows="4" cols="50" name="content"
            value="<% if(editMode) { %><%= event.content %><%}%>"></textarea>
</div>
```

I can see and use the CKEditor when I view the form.

However, when I load the form on edit mode, CKEditor is also rendering the HTML tags in the frontend.

In the database, the content is saved as follows:

[image]

See image attached

How do I properly display the content without showing the HTML?
For instance, If a text is in bold, it should show in bold, and not the strong tag itself.

[image]

Comment: Apologies, I just edited my question. Somehow what I had written was cut out.

Comment: Please have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124583/print-raw-html-strings-on-ejs) - `<%= ...` will output escaped HTML, you might want to resort to `<%- .... `

Comment: @DarkBee it does not make a difference at all whether I use equal symbol or dash.
It behaves the same even if I do not use either.

Answer (score 0):

This all turns out to be an HTML issue.

The textarea is incorrectly defined. Instead, it should looks like this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="editor" rows="4" cols="50" name="content">
    <% if(editMode) { %><%- event.content %><%}%>
</textarea>
```