# Is there a way to render rich text format fetched from MySQL, inside of html page using Express (Node js)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, richtext

I have collected my html elements as product description. But when I fetch the data I cannot render it right away on page load.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX1Ht.png)

I have did a simple assign function

```
<script>
        function parseHTML(e){
            e.innerHTML = e.innerText
        }
    </script>
```

and set it to the page element as

```
        <td onload="parseHTML(this)" data-label="description"><%=item.description%></td>
```

but it doesn't work like this. Nevertheless it is working with onclick element

Comment: Check these two posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124583/print-raw-html-strings-on-ejs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326950/render-a-variable-as-html-in-ejs

Comment: @Balaji thanks a lot, it was actually so simple :'D

Answer (score 0):

`<%-` outputs the unescaped value into the template in Express.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).